# RecyclerView.Adapter why there is a method with big letter

Tags: java, android, class

Hello I am trying to understand RecyleView.Adapter class.
I don't understand why there is the method with big letter.
Like i know, i should use name of class with big first letter and then dot + name of method or
object with small letter. There is name of class with big letter and than method with big.

Comment: please share the code that you are referring to

Comment: Kindly refer to this on how to ask a good question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Adapter" is a Nested abstract class

```
public static abstract class RecyclerView.Adapter extends Object
```